Definition of learning algorithm and successful learner
I'm currenting going through "Understanding Machine Learning from Theory to Algorithms" and I'm a little bit confused with what is meant by learning algorithm and a "sucessful learner". The book gives such concrete definitions and yet neglects to define what exactly these two concepts are/mean.
The book references a learning algorithm as taking in a sample from a distrubtion and returning a hypothesis (I think it has to be within the hypothesis space)---Is this deterministic or ...?
In the "Fundamental Theory of PAC learning" the book describes the following

Statements (2) and (5) reference a certain algorithm (ERM) being a sucessful (A)PAC learner on $\mathcal{H}$-- What exactly does this mean? My best guess is that for every $\epsilon, \delta \in (0,1)$ there is some $m(\epsilon, \delta)$ so that for every $m > m(\epsilon, \delta)$ we have with probability $1 - \delta$ over $S \sim \mathcal{D}^m$ that
$$L_{\mathcal{D}}(A(S)) \leq \epsilon$$
Which is is basically the definition of (A)PAC learning but with ERM as the specific learning algorithm -- but I'm not entirely sure since the book never gave a proper definition.
(P.S this question seems a bit obvious but the reason I'm confused has to do with a proof regarding $\mathcal{H}$ being non-uniformly learnable iff it is the countable union of hypothesis spaces that have uniform convergence)

I'm kind of confused why they used $\frac{1}{8}$ and $\frac{1}{7}$ and how those specific numbers prove anything --and especially what part of the FTSL the proof uses. I was thinking it had something to do with ERM being a sucessful learner but I have no clue--- none of my explanations make any sense (and the proof doesn't seem valid to me)
